# Spring Boot: Do I have to add a jdbc pool dependency for Oracle connection?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

First off I'm new to Spring Boot, so perhaps there is something simple I'm missing.

I have a small Spring Batch process that relies upon Spring Boot.
By default it uses the embedded H2 database.
I want it to use an oracle database.
So I set the url/username/password in the application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:batch
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=reallyCoolPassword
```

and add the dependecy to my Maven pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>${oracle.client.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I still get the embedded database. The only way I've been able to make it work is to add a dependency to a connection pool (for example tomcat).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing something? I was expecting Spring Boot to already have a dependency to tomcat that it would have brought in.  Allowing me to override with dbcp or something else if needed.

hopefully someone can tell me what I've done wrong or help me straighten out my thinking.

Comment: Do you have a dependency to `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` or `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` defined? Implicitly those starter poms will automatically get the datasource dependency (e.g. tomcat-jdbc) otherwise you will have to define it yourself. Otherwise, you only need to declare the db driver (in your pom.xml) and your datasource in application.properties and Spring should configure the rest with sensible defaults.

Comment: I'm able to connect to Oracle with only the oracle driver, the jdbc starter, and the only properties set are my connection string, username, and password. You for sure aren't overriding the autoconfiguration somehow?

Comment: Is your driver in your classpath? (I mean, don't you have errors in your pom.xml?) ... Today, here's how to get oracle's jdbc driver with maven (good luck) : https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides

Answer (score 0):

In addition to providing url, name and password for DB you need to add `spring.datasource.driverClassName`.

We are using mysql as storage and we are adding this in properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Here is also [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/batch-oracle.properties) to properties for spring batch using oracle db.

Also you need to add your driver to project and oracle due to licence restrictions does not have public maven repository so you need to install driver. Here is [useful link with walk through.](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/)

Comment: Thanks for the response Nenad,
I understand getting the Oracle Driver to work.
( I get the same behavior in Spring Boot with/without the driver specified since Srping Boot is smart enough to figure out the right Driver based on the url )
What I'm missing is why do I need to add a connection pool dependency to make the Spring Boot magic work.